# how to safely generate a SQL LIKE statement using python db-api

Tags: python, sql, sql-like, python-db-api

I am trying to assemble the following SQL statement using python's db-api:

```
SELECT x FROM myTable WHERE x LIKE 'BEGINNING_OF_STRING%';
```

where BEGINNING_OF_STRING should be a python var to be safely filled in through the DB-API. I tried

```
beginningOfString = 'abc'

cursor.execute('SELECT x FROM myTable WHERE x LIKE '%s%', beginningOfString) 
cursor.execute('SELECT x FROM myTable WHERE x LIKE '%s%%', beginningOfString)
```

I am out of ideas; what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's best to separate the parameters from the sql if you can.
Then you can let the db module take care of proper quoting of the parameters.

```
sql='SELECT x FROM myTable WHERE x LIKE %s'
args=[beginningOfString+'%']
cursor.execute(sql,args)
```

Comment: @~unutbu: thanks, that nails it. Hadn't crossed my mind to simply append the % to the string itself *before* passing it as an arg through the db-api.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:**

As Brian and Thomas noted, the **far** better way to do this would be to use:

```
beginningOfString += '%'
cursor.execute("SELECT x FROM myTable WHERE x LIKE ?", (beginningOfString,) )
```

since the first method leaves you open to SQL injection attacks.

---

Left in for history:

Try:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT x FROM myTable WHERE x LIKE '%s%%'" % beginningOfString)
```

Comment: -1 `"SELECT x FROM myTable WHERE x LIKE '%s%%'" % "doom' ; drop table x; select '"`   **Oops?**

Comment: @Brian; very valid point!  I was focusing on the syntax error; I should not have assumed that `beginning` was clean data. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: -1 removed.  You still have a syntax error, though.  Use double quotes for your string and you won't need to escape your single quotes.

Comment: Edited to fix the syntax error and the bug that Thomas pointed out.

Comment: I tried using ? instead of %s With mysql-connector-python and it did not

Answer (score -1):

Take note of [Sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) documentation:

> Usually your SQL operations will need
>   to use values from Python variables.
>   You shouldn’t assemble your query
>   using Python’s string operations
>   because doing so is insecure; it makes
>   your program vulnerable to an SQL
>   injection attack.
>
> Instead, use the DB-API’s parameter
>   substitution. Put ? as a placeholder
>   wherever you want to use a value, and
>   then provide a tuple of values as the
>   second argument to the cursor’s
>   execute() method. (Other database
>   modules may use a different
>   placeholder, such as %s or :1.) For
>   example:
>
> ```
> # Never do this -- insecure!
> symbol = 'IBM'
> c.execute("... where symbol = '%s'" % symbol)
>
> # Do this instead
> t = (symbol,)
> c.execute('select * from stocks where symbol=?', t)
>
> # Larger example
> for t in [('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000, 45.00),
>           ('2006-04-05', 'BUY', 'MSOFT', 1000, 72.00),
>           ('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
>          ]:
>     c.execute('insert into stocks values (?,?,?,?,?)', t)
> ```

I think you want this:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT x FROM myTable WHERE x LIKE '%?%', (beginningOfString,) )
```

Comment: @Thomas: Why? Other than the fact that I used `'%?%'` instead of `'?%'` (He was not fully consistent in his query which he wanted), I don't see a problem.

Comment: The problem is that the ? gets replaced by the *quoted* version of the actual argument you pass. So given, for instance "';DROP TABLE x;SELECT '" (notice the single *and* double quotes there), you end up with this obviously bad query: SELECT x FROM myTable WHERE x LIKE '%';DROP TABLE x; SELECT '%'

Comment: I don't follow.  Doesn't DB-API's parameter substitution fix that?