# Flask MySQL Search Engine on a MVC model not working

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am trying to create a search engine with Flask that finds results in my MySQL database but I have problems bringing in data that is not written exactly as it is saved.

My MODEL function

```
    @classmethod
    def search(cls, data):
        instance_results = [] 
        query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name LIKE '" + data + "%' ORDER BY id DESC"
        results = connectToMySQL('lab_bd').query_db(query, data)
        for result in results:
            instancia = cls(result)
            instance_results.append(instancia)
        return instance_results
```

My CONTROLLER function

```
@app.route('/show/patients', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def show_patients():
    if request.method=='POST' and 'txtname' in request.form:
        name = request.form["txtname"]
        data = name
        print ("DATA NAMER RUTA", data)
        users = User.search(data)
        print("SEARCH USUARIOS ", users)
    else:
        users = User.get_all()
        print("USUARIOS ", users)
    return render_template("searcher.html", users = users)
```

**BEFORE I did this and it worked but just I said on the description before.**
my  data on my route was `data = {"first_name": name}`
and my `query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name LIKE %(first_name)s ORDER BY id DESC"`

And this is my database connection I´m not sure if the problem is because of this, I´m doing it ths way because or teacher told us that it was a better method to do it because of the sql injection

```
import pymysql.cursors

class MySQLConnection:
    def __init__(self, db):
        connection = pymysql.connect(host = 'localhost',
                                    user = 'root',
                                    password = '', 
                                    db = db,
                                    charset = 'utf8mb4',
                                    cursorclass = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
                                    autocommit = True)
        self.connection = connection
    def query_db(self, query, data=None):
        with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
            try:
                query = cursor.mogrify(query, data)
                print("Running Query:", query)
     
                executable = cursor.execute(query, data)
                if query.lower().find("insert") >= 0:
                    self.connection.commit()
                    return cursor.lastrowid
                elif query.lower().find("select") >= 0:
                    result = cursor.fetchall()
                    return result
                else:
                    self.connection.commit()
            except Exception as e:
                print("Something went wrong", e)
                return False
            finally:
                self.connection.close() 
def connectToMySQL(db):
    return MySQLConnection(db)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2097475/5320906) answer your question?

Comment: Do not use concatenation to build a query string with user-supplied data. This is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection). Use parameterized queries as demonstrated in [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094159/pymysql-variables-in-queries).